# slideToogle not working properly with dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
        <div class="some-class">Stuff</div>
        <div class="this-class">
            <a class="button alt small hide-description">Toggle Description</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-child-desc">SOMETHING HIDDEN</div>
</div>
```

And this is the script I use to display .item-child-desc:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".hide-description").on("click", function(e) {
        $(e.target).parents(".item-wrapper").find(".item-child-desc").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

... that is initiated hidden:

```
.item-child-desc {
    display: none;
}
```

item-inner-wrapper gets generated every time a button is pressed and Toggle Description is displayed in a new row.

The JavaScript code I tried to create is not really working. I tried many different approaches but nothing. It only makes the first row item disappear, the others the event doesn't work.

**EDIT > RESOLVED**

Either John's or Saar's version works fine and it must be put on . Otherwise the script will be copied together with the rows and executed n times. That's why it was not working properly when I clicked to show the div.

Comment: does item-wrapper stay and only the internal part of it changes?

Comment: @Saar it gets regenerated with all its content.

Comment: so use jQuery delegation on it's parent, you need something steady

Comment: @Saar it partially worked with an upper div. However when I click to show the div it gets shown and gets hidden again. It is as if the function was being called twice.

Comment: for me it works without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a fiddle that use jQuery event delegation:

http://jsfiddle.net/hz0q0yys/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#container").on( "click", "a.hide-description", function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        $(e.target).parents(".item-wrapper").find(".item-child-desc").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: it works in the fiddle but on my code it doesn't really. Any idea why do you think it would get shown and hidden? It is as if I clicked twice in the button when I clearly did not.

Comment: I added a div called container outside of the wrapper so you understood that you need to bind to something steady

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I figured out that if the page gets generated back from a post, for example (because something was typed wrong), it gets messy and then the problem I told you appears. When I click it gets shown and hidden again.

Comment: you can try what John offered and binding it to the document which should be changed from the postback I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try event delegation this way

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(document).on("click", ".hide-description", function(e) {
    $(e.target).parents(".item-wrapper").find(".item-child-desc").slideToggle(500);   
  });
});
```

```css
.item-child-desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-wrapper">
  <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
    <div class="some-class">Stuff</div>
    <div class="this-class">
      <a class="button alt small hide-description">Toggle Description</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-child-desc">SOMETHING HIDDEN</div>
</div>
```

Comment: john, how is that different from what I wrote?

Comment: @Saar yeah, it seems to be the same thing.

Comment: @Saar I have bonded the click event with the `document` and then your fiddle example is wrong.

Comment: I guess that bonding something higher in the DOM is better? I am really not sure of that.. and my fiddle works just fine

Comment: 1. It depends upon the developer's usability.
2. I mean your first fiddle example which you have posted earlier.

Comment: @Saar Both ways I get the same result. It works but only if the page is generated from a fresh GET. If one of the fields is incorrect and then a POST method sends it back, the generated fields get bugged with this show/hide stuff.

Comment: If you can give a link or something I can help you debug it.

Comment: @Saar Thanks for your help, mate. It worked. It was being called n number of rows, since I had it inside the body and not on head. Every time I called the function it was called n times the row was generated. Thanks for the help!